# Receiving error while creating stored procedure to insert Excel files into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, syntax

I was wondering if you could tell me what is wrong with my query?

The parameter `@TableName` is an input parameter.

Why do I have to declare it again?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OpenExcel]
    @FileName nvarchar(2000),
    @TableName varchar(2000)

AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Provider nvarchar(2000)
            SET @Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

        DECLARE @etValue nvarchar(4000)
            SET @RetValue = 'select * 
                             from openrowset(''' + @Provider + 
                             ''',''Excel 8.0;Database=' + 
                             @FileName + ';hdr=no' + ''',
                             ''select " from [Sheet1$]'' )'

        DELETE FROM @TableName

        INSERT INTO @TableName

        EXEC(@RetValue)

    END
```

<sub>*[An image of the stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPkfZ.png)*</sub>

The error message I receive is:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OpenExcel, Line 26
>   Must declare the table variable "@TableName".

Well I'm trying to pass the Excel path (`@FileName`) and table name (`@TableName`; in which the data should be inserted) to the stored procedure.

How can I achieve that?

I have different tables with different structures. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[OpenExcel]

 @FileName nvarchar(2000),

  @TableName varchar(2000) 

AS Begin 

    declare @Provider nvarchar(2000);

    set @Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';

    declare @RetValue nvarchar(4000) ;

    set @RetValue='select * from openrowset("' + @Provider + ''',''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @FileName +';hdr=no'+''', ''select * from [Sheet1$]" )' 

    declare @Bufr nvarchar(4000) 

    set @Bufr='delete from '+@TableName+';'

    set @Bufr=@Bufr+'insert into '+@TableName  exec(@RetValue) 

End
```

Comment: thank you very much . the problem is that I can see the results but not in the destination table. would you mind if you test it yourself ? I can see the result of the procedure but the data won't be inserted into the destination table.

Comment: DECLARE @Bufr nvarchar(4000) 
   --SET @Bufr='delete from '+@TableName+';'
   SET @Bufr='insert into '+@TableName + 'EXEC(@RetValue) '

     EXEC (@Bufr) we have to change it this way . but this one won't work either !!! you know.. the insert part won't be executed we have to solve this issue